# Push to Multiple Repos, suppress errors

Tags: git, deployment

Our deployment system involves pushing to a remote with multiple urls.  However, one, some or all of those urls may have a more recent commit (hotfix for example), so quite rightly it will fail if the deployment is pushing an older commit than exists in the remote location.  However, this appears to be killing the entire push, rather than carrying on with the remaining locations.

Is there a way of suppressing the errors so that it attempts the push to ALL locations?

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment, but I don't seem to have enough reputation. I'm curious as to why your deployment system works like this. If it absolutely had to, you might want to know [How do I properly force a Git push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509543/how-to-properly-force-a-git-push) But it might make more sense to iterate over a series of remotes if it really comes to that. Or adding to your remote so that you pull before push.

Have you looked into submodules at all or [Nested git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871282/nested-git-repositories)

Since you asked this a few weeks ago, what have you come up with?

Answer (score 0):

I switched to a scheduled pull deployment system rather than push.  It's more secure, and any errors can't possibly affect another server.