# Git add all files also from nested git repos

Tags: git, git-add

My dotfiles repository has some tmux plugin directories which are themselves git repositories. When I do git add -all these nested repos are ignored.

Is there a way to ignore the git semantics of these nested repos and treat everything as regular files?

Answer (score 1):

> You may be looking for the Git feature called [submodules](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial). This
>   feature helps you manage dependent repositories that are nested inside
>   your main repository.

Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871282/nested-git-repositories)

Also you might want to check the .gitignore files you might have. It can prevent the nested repositories from being added.

Comment: Do I have to handle manually the submodules? The case of a repo with external plugins that are git repos themselves is pretty common. Isn't there an easy way to ignore everything except the top-level repo?

Comment: A simple `git add` should do the trick if the .gitignore files don't prevent nested repositories from being added.  After all those repos are just files. Could you post your .gitignore file and give a little more details on your project tree ?