# Visual studio code tracks one git repo only

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am working with VS Code IDE and cloned two repos.
i.e.

```
git clone url://repo1
cd new
git clone url://repo2 new2
```

However,VS code is only tracking one repo for changes. it grays out new2 folder(it is part of repo1 gitignore). also if I make any changes it does not reflect in left panel of VS code source control.

Is it possible in Visual studio code to work with two repositories and tracking/pulling/pushing changes of both repos?

*Disclaimer : I have not worked much on git or VS code earlier.*

Comment: @matt edited my question.

Comment: Old question but pretty related I guess: [Nested Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871282/nested-git-repositories)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález is it just git behaviour? or VSCode's? I am not able to figure out that.

Comment: According to the [newest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56848737/13508), "by default git does not track the .git folder of the nested repository". I'm not proficient with git so I can't add much more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to solve this issue by adding a dummy .submodules file at root folder, and adding it to .gitignore

contain of .submoudles file:

```
[submodule "your_module_name"]
    path = paht_of_submodule/
    url = dummy_string_to_satisfy_vscode
```

More details here :
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/37947 and
https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules

Comment: I solve this issue by adding .gitmodules file

Comment: The documentation mentions that the path must NOT end with "/"