# Is it possible to clone a repo within a repo and commit to just to the inner repo?

Tags: node.js, typescript, git, gitlab, exec

I'm working in typescript, react, node.js and express. In my node server I am calling `execSync` to clone another repo, add files to it, and then push those changes. Something along the lines of this:

```
execSync("git clone <sub-repo> <path-to-sub-repo> \
    && cd <path-to-sub-repo> \
    && git checkout -b <branch-name>");

alterSubRepoFiles(<path-to-sub-repo-file>, content);

execSync("cd <path-to-sub-repo> \
    && git add . \
    && git commit -m \"some message here\" \
    && git push --set-upstream origin <branch-name>);
```

However, the push part always fails. Upon further inspection I found that this code was making branches in the **outer** repo instead of the **inner** repo.

Any advice or tips on a way achieve this functionality would be much appreciated. If there is a cleaner way to achieve this I would also appreciate the advice.

Note: Both repos are hosted on gitlab.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871282/nested-git-repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871282/nested-git-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

The inner most repo will function as its own repo. Just to be on the safer side, I'd ask you to add the innermost repo in `.gitignore` file of your outer repo so that you don't accidentally end up adding the inner repo (directory) with a `git add .`