# Push a folder of a repository into another one

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, clion, github-for-windows

I have two repositories **A** and **B** in github.
I have clone repo B inside one of the A's folders and now i want to update repo A and push the folder gotten from repo B inside github using **Clion**, and what i get is this kind of folder in repo A which is empty and not clickable:

[image]

I want to know how i can update repo A and also repo B with this kind of situation in Clion.

Comment: Have a look at git submodules: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871282/nested-git-repositories). Also search SO with `git nest repository` and `git nest repo`

Comment: I want to do it in clion, is there any option for it?

Comment: Clion can handle submodules/nested repositories. Once you have it added, please make sure that all repositories are listed Preferences | Version Control | Directory Mappings

Comment: @RuslanKuleshov I have both repos in that setting and both of them are git as VCS. What i can do is that i can update repo B from repo A, but i still cant add those folders to repo A!

Answer (score 1):

You can not work with a repository inside another repository in this way. The best thing to do would be to create two separate repositories and then use the repository that you want inside a folder as a submodule. This will allow you to update the second (submodule) at the same time when you update the first repository.

See [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for more info.

Comment: Is it possible to do it Clion?

Comment: There may be a way but it is probably easier to do major git operations using the terminal

Comment: thank you very much