# Heroku/Django - No default language could be detected for this app

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Django app via Heroku for the first time.

When I run `git push heroku master` it returns this error:

```
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: e6acd22b123b939729546f4f06f368a8855a4744
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version e6acd22b123b939729546f4f06f368a8855a4744
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to vygrapp.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/vygrapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/vygrapp.git'
```

Following similar problems on SO I believe I have my file structure correctly configured - with git deployed from same place as my Procfile etc. I also have a requirements.txt file which I believe tells Heroku it's a python app - so I can't figure out why the buildpack isn't working.

Based on comments and feedback I moved all folders into root directory but receive the same error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Heroku only looks for your `Procfile`, `requirements.txt`, and `runtime.txt` in the root directory of your project. Move them up a level so they're beside your `.gitattributes`.

That should let Heroku detect that this is a Python project and get past the current error.

But your project still won't run. Out of the box, Heroku will expect your Django project to *also* be in the root directory of your repository. You can probably get it to work from a subdirectory by playing around with the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable and / or `PYTHONPATH`, but the easiest solution is to move your entire project up a directory.

I suggest you move everything from `anybody/anybody1/` to `anybody/`, then delete the now empty `anybody/anybody1/` directory.

Then commit, and redeploy.

Comment: Thank you for your response - I've followed your instructions and deleted the ``anybody1`` directory - although one remains with ``settings`` etc in it. Here is what my directory [looks like now](https://ibb.co/bvpVJhP). The error is still thrown though.

Comment: You're getting the _same_ error? What directory contains your `.git/` folder?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! [Here](https://ibb.co/QdrHs0f) is my folder structure with `.git/` unhidden - you can see there are two `.git/` folders in different directories - perhaps a clash? Apologies for the screenshot, a bit inelegant.

Comment: [Nesting Git repositories probably doesn't do what you think it does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1871282/354577). In any case, which repository are you pushing to Heroku?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance - how do I check this? First time deploying.

Comment: How are you deploying? Via `git push`? GitHub integration?

Comment: `git push` following [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/django-hosting-on-heroku/#step-6-create-a-heroku-app) `git remote -v` results in `heroku  https://git.heroku.com/vygrapp.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/vygrapp.git (push)`

Comment: And what directory are you in when you run `git push`?

Comment: `programming/projects/anybody`

Comment: And you've committed the change where you moved the files? You are _definitely_ pushing a commit where your `Procfile`, `requirements.txt`, `runtime.txt`, and your main Django project are all in that directory?

Comment: I believe so - [here](https://ibb.co/SVYv5mg) is the result of running `git status`, I ran `git commit` to 2x check too [here](https://ibb.co/DG5bH58) is the last log.

Comment: Please share text as text, not images. And ideally all of this would go into your question. Has the error message changed at all?

Comment: Will do from now, I suppose I'm not sure how deep the problem goes. The error message had not changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241054/discussion-between-deadant88-and-chris).