# Single Github repository for two local repos for a fullstack project

Tags: git, github, repository

I was working on a fullstack MEAN project and I decided to create separate local repos for client and server. The alternative was to have a single repository with separate branches for client and server but I picked the *Separate repository* approach so that I didn't have to do a merge every time I changed something on the backend branch, for having the latest backend code in the working directory when I'm working on the frontend. I now realize that I could've used the `git worktree` command maybe, but right now I have separate repos. My folder structure is like this:

```
--MyProject
    --client
        --.git
    --server
        --.git
```

I now want to add the project to GitHub but I don't want to create two separate repositories there. I want a single repository which when cloned will pull the entire project, both frontend and backend. But the repos in client and server should be isolated from each other, that is any commit in one repo should be independent of the other and their histories should be separate.

I read about a git feature called submodules but I am unsure if that is what I'm looking for. In every tutorial it's mentioned that submodules are generally used when we want to use some third party repo in our own version controlled project. Also it seems overly complex for this simple task of placing the two repos in a single container on GitHub.

Comment: What do you mean by "isolated from each other"?

Comment: @JimRedmond , isolated means when i make i make a commit in client, that has nothing to do with server repo. And hence all the history is separate as well. I want them to act like two standalone repos so I can work on the frontend and backend independently like I'm doing now.

Comment: Sorry, but if they're going to be bound within a single repo then they're going to have intermingled histories. That is the Git nature.

Comment: @JimRedmond Hence the question. Is submodules the only option and is that what I'm looking for?

Comment: It's an option, but it feels like overkill, and it will make things much more complicated to manage later. Is the only reason for this question that you want to do a single clone for both?

Comment: Yes, i would like to have single container for both on github

Comment: Since I can't convince you that *this is going to make things much, much more complicated for you*, then yes, submodules will work for that. Enjoy the extra few seconds you'll save by cloning once; you're going to spend them, plus a lot more, by trying to maintain your setup.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're making things complex. You don't need submodules here,

First you can initialize a new Git repository locally in your --MyProject folder.

```
cd MyProject
git init
```

Then do,

```
git add client
git add server
```

Then commit and push to the GitHub (make sure to create a GitHub repo first)

This way, your GitHub repository will contain both the client and server directories.
They will be isolated from each other within the repository, and users cloning the repository will get both directories but can work on them independently.

Comment: I thought nested git repos is a bad idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871282/nested-git-repositories